# Capturing old values of cell Range only works when all cells in range are selected. [Error 5 - 'Invalid procedure call or argument']

Tags: excel, vba

I log changes in cells and their old values.

The problem occurs when I:

- Copy more than one cell, and paste that while selecting a single cell.

The code works when I:

- Change a single cell
- Use Ctrl + Z
- Delete one or more cells
- Copy and paste a single cell.
- Copy and paste more than one cell. But i need to paste over a selection of cells equal to the one i copied.

Code to update to Log worksheet:

```vb
Sub addToLog(rngCell As Range, strOld, sheetName As String)
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Log").Protect Password:="Password", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Log")
        Dim intNextRow As Integer
        intNextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        .Range("A" & intNextRow).Value = rngCell.Address
        .Range("B" & intNextRow).Value = rngCell.Value
        .Range("C" & intNextRow).Value = strOld
        .Range("D" & intNextRow).Value = Environ("username")
        .Range("E" & intNextRow).Value = sheetName
        .Range("F" & intNextRow).Value = Now()
        
    End With
End Sub
```

Code to get the data from the current worksheet, and to call addToLog:

```vb
Dim OldValues As New Collection

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set OldValues = Nothing
    Dim rngOld As Range
    For Each rngOld In Target
        OldValues.Add rngOld.Value, rngOld.Address
    Next rngOld
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim sheetName As String
    sheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    Dim strOld As String

    For Each rngCell In Target
        strOld = OldValues(rngCell.Address) ' **<----The error points me to this line**
        addToLog rngCell, strOld, sheetName
        strOld = ""
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Comment: How does that work though?  In `Worksheet_SelectionChange` you have `Set OldValues = Nothing` followed by `OldValues.Add`

Comment: I initialize OldValues to Nothing, and populate it with the value and address of the Range of cells (Target) of the SelectionChange trigger (It triggers when you make a selection, and adds those cells to a Target range).



I then use the Range of cells of the Change trigger, and iterate it calling AddToLog to populate the Log worksheet with the data from the changed cells.



It also compares the old values with the new using the Address as reference, but if the selection of cells dont coincide it throws an error.

Comment: Once you `Set OldValues = Nothing`, it no longer exists as a Collection, and you can't add anything to it.  That attempt to add items should raise an error.

Comment: Confusing statement considering [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37820990/19353309) (and some small test I just did). Added "Pear" and "Apple", then `Set sColl = Nothing`, then `sColl.Add "Orange"` and with a Debug.Print was able to get Orange just fine. @TimWilliams

Comment: @Notus_Panda - indeed.  My bad - I forgot about the whole thing with `New`.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: In cases where `Target.Count` is not the same as `OldValues.Count` then maybe you need to use `Application.Undo` to restore the original values so you can log them?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the tip. I hoped i would not have to use `Application.Undo`, but it seems its the best alternative.